# Data.Frame rearrangent: Abstract code

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I try to rearrange a data.frame for my shiny app, but I cannot find out how to write abstract enough code to be effective in any case.

My current data.frame looks like:

```
Row Names         | Col1   | Col2   | Col3
----------------- | ------ | ------ | ------
Company A: lvl:1  | number | number | number
Company B: lvl:1  | number | number | number
Company C: lvl:1  | number | number | number
Company A: lvl:2  | number | number | number
Company B: lvl:2  | number | number | number
Company C: lvl:2  | number | number | number
Company A: lvl:3  | number | number | number
Company B: lvl:3  | number | number | number
Company C: lvl:3  | number | number | number
```

The column number is prefixed but the levels are determined by `input$levels`.

I try to change the data.frame format to:

```
Row Names  | Col1   | Col2.1 | Col2.2 | Col2.3 | Col3.1 | Col3.2 | Col3.3
---------- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
Company A  | number | number | number | number | number | number | number 
Company B  | number | number | number | number | number | number | number
Company C  | number | number | number | number | number | number | number
```

`.1 , .2 , .3` correspond to `lvl:1 , lvl:2 , lvl:3`. I thought about `split()`, but I cannot figure out how to generalize it enough to be applicable for any `input$levels`.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Maybe see this post: [reshape from long to wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584).